# project.build.finalName is not working with deploy-file goal

Tags: maven

can we use `project.build.finalName` in the command line options of the mvn deploy:deploy-file goal.

here is my command:

> mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=abc -Dproject.build.finalName=test -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="file_path" -Durl=url -DrepositoryId=id`

the details are :
first, there is no POM file available.

i am just executing this command to upload the artifact in nexus.

now the issue is , the artifact being uploaded has the name as : `${artifactId}-${version}`

and i dont want version in the finalname. i have alrady gone through the couple of posts and found that we can use `project.build.finalName`

but in this case , it is still uploading with version number. how can i fix that ?

Comment: You can't cause that is the based naming rule in a Maven repository....

Comment: In my case I wanted to add revision number at the end of file name and I achieved it using `-Dclassifier=${BUILD_NUMBER}`. Just in case anyone else looking for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to drop the `-Dproject.build.finalName` part and add `-DgeneratePom=true` instead, as you're already specifying the full path to the artifact via the `-Dfile`.

You cannot ***not have*** the version part when deploying to a Maven remote repository (which is what you're trying to do). When deploying to a Maven repository, your artifact's GAV (`groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`, `type` and `classifier`) coordinates will get translated into:

```
${groupId}/${artifactId}/${version}/${artifactId}-${version}.jar
```

For example, for these GAV-s:

```
groupId    : com.foo
artifactId : bar
version    : 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT
type       : jar
classifier : [null, javadoc, sources]
```

You will get a path like:

```
com/foo/bar/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/bar-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
com/foo/bar/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/bar-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
com/foo/bar/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/bar-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
```

The `-Dproject.build.finalName` is for cases, where you'd like the artifact to have a different name so that, (for example), your build process can use that for simplicity, or convenience.

If you're deploying using `deploy-file` and have no `pom.xml` file, your command-line should look something like this:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -DgroupId=com.foo \
    -DartifactId=bar \
    -Dversion=1.2.3-SNAPSHOT \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -Dfile="path\to\foo-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar" \
    -Durl=http://the-url-to-your-repository/ \
    -DrepositoryId=the-repository-id-defined-in-your-settings.xml-that-has-your-credentials
```

Comment: POM is anyway getting generated without the `-DgeneratePom=true` . but i am not getting how dropping  `Dproject.build.finalName` will solve the issue.. ? plese suggest

Comment: i updated the command as you suggestes. give me few min. will get back

Comment: It won't work, if it's not, unless you've specified a `pom.xml` that has all the required GAV info.

Comment: Ok. i have removed version part from the command as i dont have the POM.xml

Comment: I thought you asked whether "it should not be" in the command line. It should be on the command-line, sorry, it like I misunderstood your question).

Comment: still the issue. here is my maven command used : `mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=abc -DgeneratePom=true -DartifactId=xy -Dversion=$version -Dpackaging=dll -Dfile="$_" -Durl=url -DrepositoryId=id`

Comment: No. there is no error. actually, the artifact which is being uploaded has the version number. i dont want that

Comment: for example: as of now artifact is : abc-${version}.dll and what i need is : abc.dll.
please suggest

Comment: As I explained -- you cannot **not have** the version number on the remote repository. This is how things work. There is a convention that is being followed (the Maven artifact naming convention) and you can't just put an arbitrary name for the artifact when you're deploying it to a remote Maven artifact repository.

Comment: i got that. so can you please help me understand what could be the exact command i should use ?> better if you can please modify the command and paste

Comment: i am not getting , why i cant have the version number in the command ? how then maven will use version number .. how the artifact will get the version number then ...

Comment: Sorry, but i am really confused. in one way you said, you can not not have the version number and now you mentioned you can you use the version number .. simply putting , if you can please help me with real command that would be nice

Comment: You need to have the `-Dversion`. I gave you an example above in my answer. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Ok. thanks. so now i assume that there is no way to have the artifact uploaded without version number embedded in that